# Saving cropped image (displayed in another picturebox as graphics) locally

Tags: c#, image, winforms, visual-studio, crop

This is the scenario, Suppose I have two pictureboxes. ***pbSrc*** displaying the Source Image and ***pbCrop*** displaying the cropped image. My code below shows the cropped of image from ***pbSrc*** to ***pbCrop***. I tried saving it but the output was not as what I was expecting it to be :((((

```
pbCrop.Refresh();

//Prepare a new Bitmap on which the cropped image will be drawn
Bitmap sourceBitmap = new Bitmap(pbSrc.Image, pbSrc.Width, pbSrc.Height);
Graphics a = pbCrop.CreateGraphics();

//Draw the image on the Graphics object with the new dimesions
a.DrawImage(sourceBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, pbCrop.Width, pbCrop.Height), rectCropArea, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
a.Save();  //Not sure if this really does saves the image into a file :v
```

Comment: Create another `Bitmap`. Don't draw over destination `PictureBox`. Draw on a `Graphics` object which you create from the new bitmap. Then `Save` that image.

Comment: I did not used it for is says that `a.save();` saves the current state of this System.Drawing.Graphics and identifies the saved state with a System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsState.

Comment: _the output was not as what I was expecting it to be_ this is not a helpful problem description. You need to save the cropped Image, not the Graphics object. You need to create the Graphics object FromImage. And you need to set a FileNmae and best also an ImageFormat in the Image.Save() call.. - Please note: The `Graphics` object does not __contain__ any graphics; it is a **tool** that lets you draw onto a related bitmap, including a control's surface. __So you never draw ON a Graphics object, but only on a Bitamp, USING the Graphics object!__

Comment: @RezaAghaei

Thank you for your suggestion.
Did you mean this by what you said?

`Bitmap acopy = new Bitmap(pbCrop.Image, pbCrop.Width,pbCrop.Height);`
`acopy.Save(@"C:\Temp\croppedimage.jpg",ImageFormat.Jpeg);`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _it says that a.save(); saves the current state of this System.Drawing.Graphics_ Indeed. This means that you can save some __settings__ you made, change them and later restore the old ones. Example: you may want to change the __scale__ in order to draw a tiny preview and then restore to draw with the normal scale again. Graphics is a tool to draw, not a bitmap or Image !!! Other setting include Rotations, Tranlations or resolution..

Comment: try this: Bitmap outImage = new Bitmap(pbCrop.Width,pbCrop.Height,a); outImage.Save("filename");

Comment: `new Bitmap(pbCrop.Width,pbCrop.Height,a)` this will only copy the current resolution from the Graphics object `a`. To crop (not resize) you need to draw the rectangle you want into the new Bitmap, then save the new bitmap..